# Print QQuickItem to printer

Tags: c++, printing, qml, qt5, qtquick2

How to print QQuickItem to printer?

QQuickItem = basically any QML element, like Text or Rectangle, and its children

alternatively: how to convert QQuickItem to bitmap / QImage for printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to do. I haven't found any way to do this.